# Bootstrap within bootstrap?

Tags: bootstrap, validation

I want to use .632 bootstrapping to validate an algorithm. The problem is that the algorithm itself also has bootstrapping procedures. Will that cause bias? Since bootstrapping with replacement will result in duplicated samples in the training data, will the second bootstrapping strengthen this bias?